# Why does the Python Two Way Anova for Bike Sharing Result in a warning msg?

Tags: python, anova

My goal is to examine the influence of 2 different independent variables on 1 continuous dependent variable using the 2 way ANOVA.

```
bike_sharing_data = 
pd.read_csv('datasets/bike_sharing_data_processed.csv')
```

After loading the bike_sharing_data.csv into the pandas df bike_sharing_data

```
bike_sharing_data['weathersit'].unique()
```

I have 3 Weather Situations (Weathersit)) they're my 1st Categorical Variable

```
bike_sharing_data['season'].unique()
```

I have 4 season Categorical Variables

The offending line of code -

`rp.summary_cont(bike_sharing_data.groupby(['weathersit']))['cnt']`

I used the researchpy rp library statistical function summary_cont that gives me a quick statistical overview of the 3 groups of samples that I'm working with. To get the mean and Std Deviations of the groups of data.

Warning Message

> /Users/georgeng/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/researchpy/summary.py:151: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
>     l_ci = lambda x: numpy.mean(x) - (1.960 * (numpy.std(x)/numpy.sqrt(x.count() - 1)))
>   /Users/georgeng/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/researchpy/summary.py:154: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
>     u_ci = lambda x: numpy.mean(x) + (1.960 * (numpy.std(x)/numpy.sqrt(x.count() - 1)))

Anyone knows why this error is so? And how do I fix it?

Thanks
George

Answer (score 1):

The warning is `numpy.sqrt()` complaining about the domain of its argument being negative. Its argument `x.count()-1` can only be negative with a zero count. And that means that most likely `bike_sharing_data.groupby(['weathersit'])` is returning an empty group (or one of its columns does not have any values). Hence no reasonable mean or std deviation can be calculated. Can you verify this?

**Edit:**
The simplest possible example is when you have an unnamed column due to a trailing CSV separator. For example,

```
csv = StringIO("""weathersit,season,cnt,
rainy,summer,30,
rainy,spring,20,""")
bike_sharing_data = pd.read_csv(csv)
bike_sharing_data
```

is parsed by `read_csv` into:

```
>>> bike_sharing_data
  weathersit  season  cnt  Unnamed: 3
0      rainy  summer   30         NaN
1      rainy  spring   20         NaN
```

`rp.summary_cont(bike_sharing_data.groupby(['weathersit']))['cnt']` first computes statistics of all columns, including the last Unnamed column with NaNs, which are returned as NaN results and print the warning.

The simplest possible fix would be to compute statistics only of the selected column with `rp.summary_cont(bike_sharing_data.groupby(['weathersit'])['cnt'])`.

Comment: I've ran the following;
'code' print(bike_sharing_data['weathersit'].isnull()) and it returned false

Comment: Can you try `rp.summary_cont(bike_sharing_data.groupby(['weathersit'])['cnt'])` and see if it works without warnings? If it does, you simply have some other columns without values. The way you have written the code, it computes statistics of all columns then throws away everything except for statistics of 'cnt'.

Comment: yes it worked without any warnings, thanks for all your help!